# how to add img tag in td inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
 $.each(segment, function (index, innerSegment)
      {
       var tr;
         for (var i = 0; i < segment.length; i++) {
              tr = $('<tr/>');
              tr.append("<td>" + <img src="~/Content/left.jpg"/> + + segment[i].Airline.AirlineName + "</td>");
```

First thing, i am assiging data from $.each loop to a table.
In the last line as u can see, i am finding it difficult to assign
img src tag in the tr.append tag.

I am missing something in the syntax. please tell me what should i try.

Comment: FYI, `img` tag is void element, it hasn't got any closing tag `</img>`. BTW i don't understand the purpose of the `each`  loop wrapping a `for` loop??? For each `segment`, you are then looping again on each `segment`. It doesn't make sense. On `for` loop, don't you want instead to use `innerSegment`

Comment: edited ques just typo error @A.Wolff

Comment: how could anyone just downvote without even knowing proper answer? at least if u dont know the answer then keep away from question disgusting people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a simple problem in showing image in td. Howevere, I have tried all the way to show an image.Finally, this line helped me:

```
  $.each(segment, function(index, innerSegment) {
  var tr;
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append('<td><img src="../Content/left.jpg"/>' +
   innerSegment.Airline.AirlineName + "</td>");
     // rest of the code 
  });
```

Simply Replacing tilde symbol(~) with (..) did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Some error in your code

1. Misplaced closing quotes in appending string.
2. `img` tag is self closing tag and `</img>` is invalid.
3. Already you are iterating using `$.each`, so I think for loop can be avoided.

---

```
$.each(segment, function(index, innerSegment) {
  var tr;
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append('<td><img src="left.jpg"/>' +
    innerSegment.Airline.AirlineName + "</td>");
  // rest of the code 
});
```

Comment: still not getting proper image, showing like there is no img there but i have given proper img path in src attribute

Comment: `tr.append('<td><img src="~/Content/assets/img/mc.png" />'` i am using this here not getting image tried same in a div on same page like this: got proper image there `
<div class="ffl">         
    <img src="~/Content/assets/img/mc.png" />` ya as i showed path is correct

Comment: @duke : are you sure the td is getting appended.... and check the dynamically generated html code in page source....

Comment: td is getting appended and airline name is correct but no image okk let me check generated html code

Comment: the rendered html is `<td>
<img src="~/Content/assets/img/mc.png">
"Indigo"
</td>   ` @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @duke : create a static `img` tag with that path in same page , .... `<img src="~/Content/assets/img/mc.png">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113473/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-duke).